# options in select menu do not scroll in JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a a select menu in jquery mobile site you can find the work here:
http://www.emadzedan.com/TicketsJOMobile/#checkout

Note: please try to see the (Days) select menu

I tried to make it custom pop up menu but JQuery do not respond and I tried to make it native but the options do not scroll it is shown as in the link the options is long and exceeds the page height.

So I'm stuck at this (error) and I searched the internet for more than 2 days but no one is saying anything about it.

Comment: add `data-native-menu="false"` to `select`.

Comment: I tried that but it is not responding even I tried to put this code in the JS 
file$(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
    $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false;
 });

Comment: have you placed that code after jQuery.js and before jQM.js?

Comment: I tried that too but no effect happens please check the source code it is there

Comment: it's conflicting with jquery-ui.js

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: if you remove jquery-ui.js your code will work. Or load jquery-ui.js before jQM.js

Answer (score 1):

the final and perfect answer is the above to answers but two clear things up:

1)it is actually conflicting with JQuery UI and putting it before JQuery Mobile solve the issue.

but:

if you trying to use JQuery UI Menus (Styles) you need to add the following Styles in your CSS file:

```
.ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu{
     height:150px;
}
/* Note to modify the height of the select menu for specific menu use (ID-menu)*/
#year_Traveler4-menu{
    height:50px !important;
}
```

Thanks All